# Как заменить текст в элементе по клику?

Tags: html, jquery

Пробовал также вместо `.html` использовать `.text`. Не работает. Что я делаю не так?

```js
$('.expand').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var text = $this.find('.expand_text').html();

  function textToggle() {
    if ($(text) == 'expand') {
      $(text).html('To curtail');
    } else {
      $(text).html('expand');
    }
  }
  textToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment_block">
  <div class="expand">
    <img class="expand_img" src="/image/expand.png" alt="">
    <span class="expand_text">expand</span>
  </div>
  <a href="#comment" class="btn_add btn_add-top js_modal">
    <span class="com_add">Add Comments</span>
    <span class="icon icon_add">+</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Методы `html` и `text` нужно вызывать для самого элемента `.expand_text`, а не для его внутреннего html-a:

```js
$(".expand").on("click", function() {
  var $text = $(this).find(".expand_text");
  $text.text($text.text() == "expand" ? "To curtail" : "expand");
});
```

```html
<div class="expand">
  <img class="expand_img" src="/image/expand.png" alt="" />
  <span class="expand_text">expand</span>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя в JavaScript ставить знак $ перед переменной и использовать зарезервированное слово this для обозначения переменной, так что 
    var $this
неверный синтаксис

Comment: Это неправда. `$this` - это верный синтаксис, а само название `$this` часто используется для обозначения jQuery обёртки над `this`.